# Adding droidText to Android - Adding external jar to Android

Tags: android, jar

I am trying to add the external jar of droidText to my Android project.  I am using Eclipse and am working with Android 2.3 to the current version.  I have created a libs/ folder like was described in the [getting started](https://code.google.com/p/droidtext/wiki/GettingStarted) for this jar.  After the jar is in the libs/ folder, when the project tried to build, I got a `Unable to execute dex: Java heap space Java heap space` error.  I went into the Eclipse.ini file and updated the memory first to 512m and then to 1024m.  I am still getting a Java heap space error.  Should I continue to raise the memory, or is there something else I can do to make this jar work with my app.  Thanks.

Comment: it is possible that your jar requires distinct java version

Comment: It isnt specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using droidText as an Android library project instead should lower memory consumption. I updated the "Getting Started" guide to reflect that this is the recommended approach.

Please also make sure that you're running the latest ADT plugin.

If that doesn't work for you either try building via ant

Answer (score 0):

> Should I continue to raise the memory

Yes, to the extent that you can. That JAR is immense, and so I am not surprised that it causes some problems.

You might need to switch to command-line builds.

Comment: I just threw 2g at it and it still gave me the same error.  If I use a command line build, is it possible it will use less memory?

Comment: @jhamm: Well, it won't be governed by Eclipse's available heap space, which should help. It's just an educated guess, though. You might try contacting the author of the JAR to see if there are any specific recommendations.